# How to launch a non-interactive process from an interactive session

Tags: windows, interactive

The goal is to be able to test run a PowerShell script non-interactively with as little ceremony as possible.
It purposely runs differently on the CI server than it does when I run it interactively and I'd like to debug it. Ideally I could test this without having to set up a scheduled task. A command line utility would be fantastic.

What's different between the CI server (TFS build, non-interactive) and my machine (running interactively) is the value of `[Environment]::UserInteractive`. When I type `powershell -c [Environment]::UserInteractive` at the command line, I get `True` as expected. The goal is to be able to type `someutility powershell -c [Environment]::UserInteractive` and have it print `False`, just like it would print running under TFS build.

I'm willing to write the `someutility` in C++ if someone can outline how this works. I'm researching but an hour hasn't yielded anything. Everyone is already running non-interactive or wants to launch interactive, and I'm in the exact reverse scenario. It seems that there should be a way to do this from a non-administrator command line since the launched process should have the same user permissions but be restricted to non-interactive.

So far, I can get this desired `[Environment]::UserInteractive` = false behavior using a scheduled task and picking "Run whether user is logged on or not." But it's a pain, and I can't see the non-interactive stdout which I know is possible because TFS build shows it live. Also, the scheduled task doesn't end when run non-interactively so it's hard to tell when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The reference code for UserInteractive can be found here.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,87db1f60fca84037)  It sets the property to false if and only if the window station for the process does not have the `WSF_VISIBLE` flag set.  So your utility should create a new window station and desktop (see [CreateWindowStation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682496(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CreateDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124(v=vs.85).aspx)) and launch the child process there.

(Only the default window station for any given session is interactive, so presumably manually created window stations will not have `WSF_VISIBLE` set by default.  If this does not turn out to be the case, you should be able to use [SetUserObjectInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686287(v=vs.85).aspx) to toggle the flag.)

To choose the window station and desktop for a child process, specify it in the `lpDesktop` member of the `STARTUPINFO` structure in the call to [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).